# Reduction from $HALT$ to $A_{TM}$

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

I know the reduction to from $A_{TM}$ to $HALT$. But is
the following reduction **from** $HALT$ to $A_{TM}$ correct?

We are looking for total computable function $f$ mapping from $HALT$ to $A_{TM}$.
The following TM $F$ calculates the reduction $f$.

```
F = on input <T, w>
    create the following TM T':
    T' = on input v:
       start T on v
       if T accepts or rejects, *accept*
    return <T',w>
```

I think the line `if T accepts or rejects, *accept*` is correct, but it would be great if someone could check this.

Edit: I found the following slides, but I don't think the construction in there is correct: http://slideplayer.com/slide/13791105/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple notions of "reduction." You've correctly described a **many-one reduction** of $HALT$ to $A_{TM}$. The reduction you've linked to (with the proof on [slide 24](http://slideplayer.com/slide/13791105/85/images/24/Example+reduction+Deciding+HALT+using+a+procedure+that+decides+ATM+%28+reducing+HALT+to+ATM+%29.+on+input+%3CM%2C+w%3E.jpg) of the [deck you linked](http://slideplayer.com/slide/13791105/)) is instead a **truth-table reduction**. These are more general objects (so your result is stronger). Each is in turn subsumed by the much broader notion of **Turing reduction**.

While many-one reductions are generally the default notion in complexity theory, Turing reductions and the resulting [degree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) are the default in computability theory. Note that if all I want to do is prove the undecidability of some set, a Turing reduction from some known-to-be-undecidable set is sufficient.

---

First, let's explicitly recall the definitions of the languages involved:

- $A_{TM}=\{\langle M,w\rangle: M$ halts and accepts on input $w\}$.
- $HALT=\{\langle M,w\rangle: M$ halts on input $w\}$.

Your proposed reduction of $HALT$ to $A_{TM}$ is **correct**: given $M$, we can computably build a new machine $\hat{M}$ which accepts precisely those strings on which $M$ halts. (Basically, just replace all the "reject" states in $M$ by "accept" states.)

---

Now let's look at the other reduction which you linked to (the aforementioned [slide 24](http://slideplayer.com/slide/13791105/85/images/24/Example+reduction+Deciding+HALT+using+a+procedure+that+decides+ATM+%28+reducing+HALT+to+ATM+%29.+on+input+%3CM%2C+w%3E.jpg), reproduced below).

> ### Example reduction
>
> - Deciding $HALT$ using a procedure that decides $A_{TM}$ (“reducing $HALT$ to $A_{TM}$”)
>
>   - On input $\left<M, w\right>$
>   - Check if $\left<M, w\right>\in A_{TM}$
>
>     - if yes, the[n] $M$ halts on w; **ACCEPT**
>     - if no, then $M$ either rejects *w* or it loops [o]n $w$
>   - construct $M'$ by swapping $q_{accept}$/$q_{reject}$ in $M$
>   - check if $\left<M', w\right>\in A_{TM}$
>
>     - if yes, then $M'$ accepts $w$, so $M$ rejects $w$; **ACCEPT**
>     - if no, then $M$ neither accepts nor rejects $w$; **REJECT**

Basically, rather than going to "all halting states accept" the linked argument considers separately:

- the original machine, and
- the "contrary" machine which accepts exactly when the original one rejects and vice-versa.

An affirmative answer for either case in $A_{TM}$ ensures an affirmative answer for the original machine in $HALT$.

Off the top of my head I see no reason to do this rather than follow your argument, especially because it yields a weaker result, but it is correct and is enough to prove the broader claim in the slides, namely that $A_{TM}$ is undecidable.